# Unknown users rights (-????????? ? ? ? ? ? myFile.php)

Tags: linux, admin, chmod, rights

I have some weirds user rights on my files.

Log as user1, I have set user2 owner of the files. It did worked.

```
       -rw-r-xr-x 1 user2 user2 21090 Jun 18 16:28 myFile.php
       drw-r-xr-x 2 user2 user2  4096 Jun 18 16:30 font
```

But then, when I log with user2 I Have this weirds unknown rights.

```
       -????????? ? ? ? ?              ? myFile.php
       d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? font/
```

Comment: ask at [unix stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) .

Comment: Try running `fsck`. Your file system might be corrupt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Top directory that contains these files has no "x" bit set.

```
chmod u=rwx test2/; ls -l test2
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 user group 4096 Jun 19 14:43 dir
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group    0 Jun 19 14:43 file

chmod u=rw test2/; ls -l test2
ls: cannot access test2/file: Permission denied
ls: cannot access test2/dir: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? dir
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file
```

To fix this, please add "x" bit to following section of root directory. Usually "group" part is relevant but it might be "others" or "user" depending on your situation.

```
chmod g+x /path/to/directory
```

For further reading please consult http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions